# Where can I find the supported way to deploy hadoop on precise?

Tags: 12.04, apt, hadoop

I want to set up a small (6 node) hadoop/hive/pig cluster.

I see the work in the juju space on charms; however, the current status of deploying a single charm per node will not work for me.

I see [ServerTeam Hadoop](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/Hadoop) which talks about re-packaging the bigtop packages.

The cloudera CDH3 [installation guide](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/CDH3+Installation#CDH3Installation-InstallingCDH3onUbuntuandDebianSystems) talks about Maverick and Lucid, but not precise.

What am I missing?  Is there a straight forward way to deploy hadoop/hive/pig on 6 nodes that does not involve building from tarballs?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no "supported" way yet (by "supported" i mean packages in the default repositories maintained by Canonical).

From the links you provide, [“Hadoop Ubuntu Packagers” team](https://launchpad.net/~hadoop-ubuntu) has 3 ppa's with packages to precise (dev, testing and stable). If using a PPA is an option then choose the one best fits your needs.

CDH4 provides packages to precise (although it seems quite different from CDH3). Despite not being supported you can try to use maverick repo in precise.

Also [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) provides compiled versions of Hadoop, so you dont need to build them from source, but you probably will need to setup the init scripts and configure Hadoop manually.

Hope this helps somehow.